# What informataion analysis techniques are there for the qualitative analysis of user generated data?

Tags: semantics, data-analysis

There's a few algorithms we have for sorting data, finding the maximum and minimum, finding the shortest path between nodes etc.

I've started looking into the qualitative analysis of user-generated data and have come across [latent semantic anaylsis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_semantic_analysis). What other techniques exists for the analysis of textual data ... and possibly other media?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's...a pretty broad question.  Analysis of user-generated data, textual or otherwise, is typically done through specialized applications of general [data mining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_mining) techniques.  If you're interested in learning more about this extremely wide field, I'd start with that wikipedia link, follow all *its* references, then hit Google Scholar.  By then you should know what sorts of techniques you're interested in.

If you have a specific problem in mind, post about it; there's a community of AI guys here on SO and one of us can probably suggest an approach, or at least a more focused line of research.